# How to retrieve a property value of a vertex in python gremlin

Tags: python, gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

It might be easy, but I am really struggling with this problem. I use gremlin python lib and aws neptune db.
I know the vertex id, I just want to get the value(String type in python) of one of the properties of the vertex, and update it.

I have tried to do like this:

```
print(g.V(event['securityEventManagerId']).values('sourceData'))
print(g.V(event['securityEventManagerId']).property('sourceData'))
print(g.V(event['securityEventManagerId']).property('sourceData').valueMap())
.....
```

But I just print some python gremlin object like `GraphTraversal`, cannot retrieve the value as a `string`

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use a terminal step, without them your query will not execute.

From tinkerpop [documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.3/reference/):

> Typically, when a step is concatenated to a traversal a traversal is returned. In this way, a traversal is built up in a fluent, monadic fashion. However, some steps do not return a traversal, but instead, execute the traversal and return a result. These steps are known as terminal steps (terminal) and they are explained via the examples below.

In your case, you should do:

```
g.V(event['securityEventManagerId']).values('sourceData').next()
```

Comment: Also helpful in understanding this concept: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#result-iteration

Answer (score 3):

Here's a snippet:

```
for p in g.V(v).properties():
   print("key:",p.label, "| value: " ,p.value)
```

where v is the vertex you want to inspect.